# Move contents of one directory to another using Perl

Tags: perl, move

Is it possible to use Perl's move function from File::Copy or any other perl module to replace

```
system("mv -f /../directory1/* /../directory2/");
```

OR

replace a code like,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $dir1= "/..path../directory1";
my $dir2="/..path../directory2";

opendir  DH, $dir1;
while(my $file = readdir DH)    {
    move "$dir1/$file" , "$dir2/$file";
    }
closedir DH;
```

What i want to do is move all the contents from directory1 to directory2 using some Perl module, instead of writing a code for it.

Exploring the possibility of using a simple perl line, may be like,

```
move ("directory1/*","directory2/" ) ;  using some perl module.
```

Comment: In your question, you seem to be moving files from `directory1` to... `directory`. Could you double-check that first line of code?

Comment: Thanks QPaysTaxes, that was a typo

Comment: No, `File::Copy` does not allow wildcards.

Comment: Looks like rmove_glob() might be the answer from File::Copy::Recursive. I need to explore to confirm on this.

Comment: Are you on Linux - why not invoke cp?  If dir2 can be overwritten then that should be a fast operation.  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=380670 talks about backticks vs system()

Comment: Yes, I am on linux and in linux mv is faster than cp as far as i know. I dont want to use cp because, my dir1 should get empty (and the dir1 should be retained). A poor way will be mv the entire dir1 and then mkdir dir1, but I am using multi-threads. So if there is a slight sync prob in removal and mkdir of directories, there will be  errors like "shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory", etc...

Comment: Using system() will also make it slow and hence multi thread issues will crop up

Comment: Why do you insist on using a third-party module? Simply implement the function yourself and optionally put it in your own module.

Comment: Yes, nwellnhof, that's what is the ultimate solution. But sometimes I do feel re-inventing wheel always may not be a good idea as it is not a good use of existing resources and time.